# Whose surgery was Stephen Strange undertaking during the New York attack?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, doctor-strange

In *Avengers: Endgame* Bruce Banner/Professor Hulk travels back in time to the New York attack depicted in the first *Avengers* movie and runs into the Ancient One, who tells him that Stephen Strange is currently performing surgery somewhere in the city (and not a master of the mystic arts yet).

However, in *Doctor Strange* we see Strange take a call about someone with a spinal injury from a prototype battlesuit just as he crashes his vehicle and can no longer perform surgery. I've read that this person was the unfortunate Hammer test-pilot we see during the Senate hearing in *Iron Man 2* - but that event is long before the New York attack, so how is Stephen Strange performing surgery after his injuries (before learning to overcome them at Kamar-Taj)?

Comment: I haven't seen Doctor Strange - is there any reference in there to what he was doing during the attack on New York? Could have been he was just doing his job - surgery.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what you're asking. Can you clarify what it is you're confused about and why?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure that this is unclear.  As @HorusKol states, its about the timeline of Doctor Strange in relation to the attack on New York in 2012.

Comment: I do feel that the "prototype suit" is a bit of a red herring and is not positively identified.  What is identified is that the Stark Tower in Doctor Strange looks like it does in Age of Ultron (it has an Avengers A on it) - indicating it is post 2012, so its clear that Strange is "just a surgeon" isn't a a goof.

Comment: Hi @BenSilby - I've tried to improve your question without changing the original premise - could you take a look and see if my changes a inline with your original intent? Perhaps we can get this reopened for you.

Comment: Couldn't it be just a common patient like that in _Doctor Strange_?

Answer (score 3):

We don't know who is undergoing the surgery that Strange is performing during the New York attack.

I'm not sure what you've read regarding the identity of the battle-suit injury being discussed immediately prior to Strange's car crash, but the only references I can find to support it being the Hammer pilot from *Iron Man 2* are unsupported fan theories.

If we look at the MCU timeline, we see that Strange's crippling injury took place in February 2016, which is several years after the battle of New York in the *Avengers* movie - so there is no reason he cannot perform surgery at the time Banner meets the Ancient One.